# Arduino motor speed and direction

Tags: performance, bluetooth, arduino

I would like to make a program to control my Arduino Bluetooth car.
I'm having lots of trouble making it in a desired  direction and at a desired speed. So far I tried this, but for some reason it is not working:

```cpp
int motor1clock = 7, motor1clockc = 8, pwm1 = 3, pwm2 = 9, motor2clock = 10, motor2clocko = 16, speed;
String inputString = "", junk;

void setup()
{
    pinMode(motor1clock, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(motor1clockc, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(pwm1, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(motor2clocko, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(motor2clock, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(pwm2, OUTPUT);
    Serial1.begin(9600);
}
void Forwards(int spee)
{
    analogWrite(pwm2, spee);
    analogWrite(pwm1, spee);
    digitalWrite(motor1clock, LOW);
    digitalWrite(motor1clockc, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(motor2clocko, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(motor2clock, LOW);
}
void Backwards(int spee)
{
    analogWrite(pwm2, spee);
    analogWrite(pwm1, spee);
    digitalWrite(motor1clock, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(motor1clockc, LOW);
    digitalWrite(motor2clocko, LOW);
    digitalWrite(motor2clock, HIGH);
}
void Steer_Left(int spee)
{
    analogWrite(pwm2, spee - 20);
    analogWrite(pwm1, spee);
    digitalWrite(motor1clock, LOW);
    digitalWrite(motor1clockc, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(motor2clocko, LOW);
    digitalWrite(motor2clock, HIGH);
}
void Steer_Right(int spee)
{
    analogWrite(pwm2, spee);
    analogWrite(pwm1, spee - 20);
    digitalWrite(motor1clock, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(motor1clockc, LOW);
    digitalWrite(motor2clocko, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(motor2clock, LOW);
}
void loop()
{
    if (Serial1.available() > 0) {
        String str = Serial1.readString();
        char inChar[3];
        str.toCharArray(inChar, 3);

        while (Serial1.available() > 0) {
            junk = Serial1.readString();
        }
        int num = atoi(&inChar[1]);
        speed = num;
        Serial1.println(speed);
        if (inChar[0] == 'A') {
            Serial1.println(inChar[0]);
            Forwards(speed);
        }

        if (inChar[0] == 'B') {

            Backwards(speed);
        }

        if (inChar[0] == 'C') {
            Steer_Left(speed);
        }

        if (inChar[0] == 'D') {

            Steer_Right(speed);
        }
        if (inChar[0] != 'A' || inChar[0] != 'B' || inChar[0] != 'C' || inChar[0] != 'D') {
            digitalWrite(motor1clock, LOW);
            digitalWrite(motor1clockc, LOW);
            digitalWrite(motor2clocko, LOW);
            digitalWrite(motor2clock, LOW);
        }
        inputString = "";
    }
}
```

The input code format would be "command speed", for example: "A255".

Comment: Besides you trying to put potentially 5 characters (string length + null terminator) into an array of 3 characters, [`Serial1.readString()`](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Serial/ReadString) has 1 second of delay. Fix it by sending lines and use [`Serial1.readStringUntil('\n')`](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/StreamReadStringUntil).

Comment: Also "*not working*" is not really a good description of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

There are more than 3 bytes in string "A255", so I recommend you to define inChar[6].
And, did "Serial1.println(speed);" print the desired speed?